# Does anyone use Datomic to get the structure and entities separately?

Tags: clojure, datomic

So I use `queries` to filter data and then use `pull` to get the information out from the Datomic database.

```
(def rules
 [[[search ?txt ?id] [(fulltext $ :artist/name ?txt) [[?id]]]]
  [[search ?txt ?id] [(fulltext $ :track/name ?txt) [[?id]]]]])

(d/q
'[:find [(pull ?id [* {:track/artists [:db/id :track/name] :track/_artists [:db/id :artist/name] }]) ...]
  :in $ % ?query
  :where [search ?query ?id]]
 db rules "John Lennon")
```

And sometimes these queries can get recursive, so for example I can change the `pull` to:

```
(d/q
'[:find [(pull ?id [* {:track/artists [:db/id :track/name] :track/_artists [* {:track/artists [:db/id :track/name]}]}]) ...]
  :in $ % ?query
  :where [search ?query ?id]]
 db rules "John Lennon")
```

Now what I'd like to do is ensure that unique entities are being returned along with the `:db/id` structure as I don't want to return duplicate data as much as possible.

For example: (results elided with ...)

```
{:entities [{:db/id 1 :track/name "..." ...} {:db/id 2 :track/name "..." ...} {:db/id 3 :artist/name "..." ...}]
 :structure [{:db/id 1 :track/artists [{:db/id 3}]} {:db/id 2 :track/artists [{:db/id 3}]}]}
```

Can this be done at the query level? Or do I need to walk the structure after the query returns and modify it? I'm happy to walk the structure at present, I'm just wondering if anyone has worked out a better approach?